# How can I retrieve the port from a crust Session?

Tags: rust

I'm trying the examples from the [`crust`](https://crates.io/crates/crust) crate but cannot figure how to obtain the port from a peer I'm connected to.

The crust example includes the following function

```
use crust::Service;

pub fn print_connected_nodes(&self, service: &Service) {
    println!("Node count: {}", self.nodes.len());
    for (id, node) in &self.nodes {
        let ip = service.get_peer_ip_addr(node).unwrap();
        let status = if service.is_connected(node) {
            "Connected   "
        } else {
            "Disconnected"
        };

        println!("[{} - {}] {} {:?}", id, ip, status, node);
    }

    println!();
}
```

There I can establish a connection and obtain the IP address with `let ip = service.get_peer_ip_addr(node)` but after reading the documentation I cannot find any method to obtain the port.

Is there another method to obtain the port?

Comment: It is unclear what you currently have and why that attempt does not work. Please provide a proper [mcve]. The [rust tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) also provides some tips towards creating an MCVE.

Comment: I have edited the question, but some details are still missing: that function is a method, you must also specify what is being implemented here.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source for `get_peer_ip_addr`](https://docs.rs/crust/0.31.0/src/crust/main/service.rs.html#227-229), it uses `get_peer_socket_addr` to get the socket, which contains both the address and the port. Unfortunately `get_peer_socket_addr` is private, so you can't get the port. There is an [open question](https://github.com/maidsafe/crust/issues/1152) about this issue in the crust bugtracker.